# Is there a way to leave the even pages blank within one chapter only?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, blank-page

I'm writing a thesis and would like the contents to be printed on odd pages only (when using a duplex printer, the rest of the thesis should be printed double-sided).
I would also like to have this for the acknowledgments (which exceeds 2 pages).

(`\cleardoublepage` will not do the work, since it cares only about the first page.)

I'm using `twoside` option.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This doesn't work very well with floats:

Here a partial solution which adds empty even pages for a chapter.
You also want to change the margins to look like for `onside`, do you?
Also the empty pages are still numbered. Simply reducing the page number by one might cause issues.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\newcommand*{\oddpagesonly}{%
    \def\emptyevenpage{%
        \afterpage{%
            \suppressfloats
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \null\newpage
        \emptyevenpage}%
    }%
    \emptyevenpage
}

\newcommand*{\allpages}{%
    \let\emptyevenpage\relax
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1-30]

\chapter{Two}
\oddpagesonly
\lipsum[1-30]

\allpages
\chapter{Three}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of doing this would be, if you need this special configuration for a limited number of pages, to use the following code:

```
\afterpage{
\null
\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage}
```

This code should be put anywhere in the page before the blank page you want to insert.

Of course you need to put `\usepackage{afterpage}` in the preamble.

It is also possible to play with the numbering a little by putting a `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` before the `\clearpage` command.

Comment: My idea exactly, but you need a recursive macro otherwise you have to add it manually to every real page of that chapter. However, it seems that the `\afterpage` code is executed AFTER some full page floats are typeset, which breaks th every even page is empty scheme :-(

Comment: @Martin. True, this is an other problem I did not take into account. The manual behaviour was intended, since it seems to me that he wants to do this for a few instances, and since it is easier than a macro. Otherwise, it is fairly easy to do the recursive macro, but not to deal with the floats.